# FBSDKGraphRequest does not fetch cover photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

The below code to fetch cover photo used to work perfectly. Now it does not fetch cover photo. Even though "Graph API Explorer" tool still works.

**Works:** Graph API Explorer

```
request = "me?fields=name,picture,cover"
```

**Doesn't Work:**

It fetches name,picture but not cover. Don't know why but previously it used to fetch all items.

Read Permission is self.fbLoginButton.readPermissions=@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends",@"user_photos"];

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=name,picture,cover"
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

The logs shows **keys** for  "name","picture" but nothing for "cover".

```
{
    id = 123123123123;
    name = “namessssss”;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = “some url for profile picture“;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: What did you use to find out it doesn't fetch cover ? NSLog ? or TableView ? Can you post your NSLog ?. Also, have you tried Facebook Graph Explorer tool ?

Comment: You can use this to see the fetched results: `FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
    initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
           parameters:@{ @"fields": @"name, picture, cover",}
           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(result)
}];`

Comment: @Suhaib no luck with that too.

Comment: Then this means there is nothing wrong with your code, the problem is that what you are fetching didn't set a cover. Try to fetch something else to make sure your code 100% works. For example: `initWithGraphPath:@"/MSFTImagine.CA/events" parameters:@{ @"fields": @"name, cover"}`

Comment: This works. But don't know why "cover" tag in my above code  does not work.

Comment: Is there a way to debug , as it does not show any error.

Comment: You need to make sure that the user you are fetching from or (the Facebook page) has uploaded a Cover Photo and already using it in his page. That is the only solution

Comment: as Mentioned the Graph API is working.

Comment: oh, ok. Can you post the whole code that you use ? like what you do after you fetch ?